# Solve a third order non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following non-homogeneous differential equation?

$$x^3u'''-3x^2u''+7xu'-8u= f $$

I really have no idea where to start and what is the homogeneous  solution ?

while $~f~$ is :

$$f=\frac{x^2}{ 1+(\ln|x|)^2}\qquad
\text{and}\quad f(0)=0$$

Comment: It's a Cauchy-Euler equation. Start there. Do you know what $f$ is?

Comment: yes it's given ;

Comment: how to solve it on R separately R+ and R- .. with f(x)??

Comment: Please type up what $f$ is, and if you want to solve separately on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}^-,$ include that in your problem write-up as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3u'''-3x^2u''+7xu'-8u= f\qquad........(1)$$
Homogeneous equation is:$$x^3u'''-3x^2u''+7xu'-8u= 0\qquad ........(2)$$

Let $~x=e^z\quad \implies z=\log x~$, then
$$u'=\frac{du}{dx}\implies \frac{du}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}\implies xu'=\frac{du}{dz}=Du\qquad\text{where}\quad D\equiv \frac{d}{dz}$$
Similarly,
$$x^2~u''=D(D-1)u\qquad \text{and}\quad x^3~u'''=D(D-1)(D-2)u$$
Equation $(2)$ becomes,
$$\{D(D-1)(D-2)-3D(D-1)+7D-8\}u=0$$
$$\implies \{D^3-6D^2+12D-8\}u=0$$

$$\implies (D-2)^3u=0$$

Roots of the trial solution are $~2,~2,~2~$, so

General solution of the equation $(2)$ is $$u=(A+Bz+Cz^2)e^{2z}$$i.e., $$u=\{A+B~\log x~+C~(\log x)^2\}~x^2$$where $~A,~B,~C$ are constants.

---

Now putting $~x=e^z\quad \implies z=\log x~$ in $~f=\frac{x^2}{ 1+(\ln|x|)^2}~\implies f=\frac{e^{2z}}{ 1+z^2}$

For Particular Integral (P.I.),

P.I.$~=~\frac{1}{(D-2)^3}\frac{e^{2z}}{ 1+z^2}=\frac{1}{(D-2)^3}{e^{2z}}{ (1+z^2)^{-1}}$

$~=~e^{2z}~\frac{1}{(D+2-2)^3} ~(1+z^2)^{-1}$

$~=~e^{2z}~\frac{1}{D^3}~ (1+z^2)^{-1}$

$~=~e^{2z}~\frac{1}{D^2}~ \tan^{-1}z$

$~=~e^{2z}~\frac{1}{D}~\left\{z~\tan^{-1}z+\frac{1}{2} \log(1+z^2)\right\}$

$~=~-\frac{e^{2z}}{2}~\left\{(1-z^2)~\tan^{-1}z+z~\log(1+z^2)-z\right\}$

$~=~-\frac{x^2}{2}~\left\{(1-(\log x)^2)~\tan^{-1}(\log x)+(\log x)~\log(1+(\log x)^2)-(\log x)\right\}$

Hence the general solution of the equation $~(1)~$ is

$$u=\{A+B~\log x~+C~(\log x)^2\}~x^2-\frac{x^2}{2}~\left\{(1-(\log x)^2)~\tan^{-1}(\log x)+(\log x)~\log(1+(\log x)^2)-(\log x)\right\}$$where $~A,~B,~C$ are constants.

> For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) there are some general rules
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{D + a} \phi (x) = e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}\phi(x)$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax} \phi(x) = e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x)$
>
> $3.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \sin ax  = $Imaginary part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $4.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \cos ax  = $Real part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $5.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} (\cos ax + i\sin ax)  = \frac{1}{f(D)} x^n e^{iax}=e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$

Answer (score 0):

Start with $u=x^k$ and plug in your homogeneous equation to find values of $k$

These values help you to find the homogeneous solution.

The particular solution depends on the structure of your $f$.

You may use the method of undetermined coefficients or variation of constants to find the particular solution.

Comment: well they were  all the same .. m1=m2=m3=2 ... what do I do.

Comment: Try $u= vx^2$ and see if you can find a function $v$ which makes sense.

Comment: is this a different method ?

Comment: Sort of like the reduction of order. If  the resulting equation is solvable,then you have a solution in form of $vx^2$

Comment: is this to the  homogeneous  one or Nonhomogeneous  ??

Comment: because I'm done with the  homogeneous .

Comment: You need three linearly independent solutions for the homogeneous equation.

Comment: isn't the solution c1x^2 + c2x^2ln(x) ??

Comment: You still need one more linear independent solution for the homogeneous equation

Comment: well is it c1e^2x  + c2xe^2x + c3x^2e^2x   ????

Comment: The $x^2 \ln x$ was correct. I am not sure about your $e^{2x}$

Comment: but it was uncompleted ... how do I complete them to follow the rule that the dim of  solutions space is 3  .. what is the third function according to Cauchy-Euler method ??

Comment: Find the third solution using $$u=w_1x^2+w_2x^2 \ln x$$

Comment: and then ?? ... do I plugged in there ??  ... and w1 and w2 are they constants ???

Comment: No, they are functions that you find by plugging in.

Comment: are they (c1 +c2ln(x) + c3(ln(x))^3) x^2  ???